# Converting any object to a byte array in java

Tags: java, serialization, arrays

I have an object of type X which I want to convert into byte array before sending it to store in S3. Can anybody tell me how to do this? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you make any attempt to read the documentation before asking this question?

Comment: Hi I did. The problem is the only way for me to add is using an existing API that we have internally and use that to put data in. My object gets generated at runtime and gets the data from another object and is not serializable. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Ah, that makes it a very different question! You should really have mentioned that your objects are not Serializable in the question - because you didn't, all the answers you've been given involve standard Java serialization, which is not applicable. You might want to ask a new question like "How can i serialize objects which do not implement Serializable?". The byte array part is not really relevant, assuming you know how to write a stream into a byte array, which you do now you've read Henrik's answer.

Comment: @BhartiRawat - did you read any of the preceding comments? BTW the "tutorial" you linked provides an excellent example of what NOT to do along with an inexplicable attempt to reverse engineer Java's serial format from a stream when the former is already thoroughly documented by ObjectOutputStream and friends.

Answer (score 104):

What you want to do is called "[serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#Java)". There are several ways of doing it, but if you don't need anything fancy I think using the [standard Java object serialization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serialTOC.html) would do just fine.

Perhaps you could use something like this?

```
package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Serializer {

    public static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException {
        try(ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream()){
            try(ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b)){
                o.writeObject(obj);
            }
            return b.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try(ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)){
            try(ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b)){
                return o.readObject();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

There are several improvements to this that can be done. Not in the least the fact that you can only read/write one object per byte array, which might or might not be what you want.

Note that "Only objects that support the [`java.io.Serializable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface can be written to streams" (see [`java.io.ObjectOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)).

Since you might run into it, the continuous allocation and resizing of the [`java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) might turn out to be quite the bottle neck. Depending on your threading model you might want to consider reusing some of the objects.

For serialization of objects that do not implement the `Serializable` interface you either need to write your own serializer, for example using the read*/write* methods of [`java.io.DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and the get*/put* methods of [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) perhaps together with reflection, or pull in a third party dependency.

[This site](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki/) has a list and performance comparison of some serialization frameworks. Looking at the APIs it seems [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/) might fit what you need.

Comment: Hi Thanks again. I couldn't get that going because the object is of a type which is being generated and I cannot make it serializable as the other person pointed it out. The API that I already have uses byte array and I can't seem to figure that out. Is there any other way or am I missing something?

Comment: Alright, I added a short section on where to get other serializers.

Answer (score 7):

Use `serialize` and `deserialize` methods in `SerializationUtils` from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/).

Comment: i used it and its slow on my reading from my disk am searching alternaive like kryo and fst

Answer (score 4):

Yeah. Just use [binary serialization](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Serializerclass.htm). You have to have each object use `implements Serializable` but it's straightforward from there.

Your other option, if you want to avoid implementing the Serializable interface, is to use reflection and read and write data to/from a buffer using a process this one below:

```
/** 
 * Sets all int fields in an object to 0.
 *
 * @param obj The object to operate on.
 *
 * @throws RuntimeException If there is a reflection problem.
 */
 public static void initPublicIntFields(final Object obj) {
    try {
       Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getFields();
       for (int idx = 0; idx < fields.length; idx++) {
          if (fields[idx].getType() == int.class) {
              fields[idx].setInt(obj, 0);
          }
       }
    } catch (final IllegalAccessException ex) {
       throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
 }
```

[Source](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/Howtosetpublicfieldobjects.htm).

Comment: Hi Thanks again. I couldn't get that going because the object is of a type which is being generated and I cannot make it serializable as the other person pointed it out. The API that I already have uses byte array and I can't seem to figure that out. Is there any other way or am I missing something?

Comment: Reflection might be the way to go. But if the process is already being used and working, and you just need help figuring it out, maybe you could post some code in another question and get help that way.

Comment: @cacho link repaired ;)

Answer (score 3):

As i've mentioned in other, similar questions, you may want to consider compressing the data as the default java serialization is a bit verbose.  you do this by putting a GZIPInput/OutputStream between the Object streams and the Byte streams.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the **object to a byte array** use the  concept of `Serialization and De-serialization`.

The complete **conversion from object to byte array** explained in is tutorial.

> http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/

```
Q. How can we convert object into byte array?

Q. How can we serialize a object?

Q. How can we De-serialize a object?

Q. What is the need of serialization and de-serialization?
```