# In Java, how to convert a list of objects to byte array?

Tags: java, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting any object to a byte array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837698/converting-any-object-to-a-byte-array-in-java)

I have a class that needs to be cached. The cache API provides an interface that caches `byte[]`. My class contains a field as `List<Author>`, where `Author` is another class. What is the correct way for me to turn `List<Author>` to `byte[]` for caching? And retrieve the `byte[]` from cache to reconstruct the `List<Author>`?

More detail about `Author` class: it is very simple, only has two `String` fields. One `String` field is possible to be `null`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Author class should implement `Serializable`

Then you can use `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize the object and `ByteArrayOutputStream` to get it written as bytes.

Then deserialize it using ObjectInputStream and convert back.

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    oos.writeObject(list);
    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: This is closed so not sure whether people can read it or not. But let's test the power of stackoverflow: when I implements Serializable interface, I am supposed to provide a serialVersionID, which should be a UID. The question is, whether I am supposed to provide it or fine to leave it out. If I am supposed to provide it, how? Any UID is fine?

Answer (score 2):

Make the `Author` class serializable and write the list to an `ObjectOutputStream` backed by a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your class Serializable; create an ObjectStream over a ByteStream and write your list to the ObjectStream.  Pass the byte buffer from the ByteStream to your caching API.

When retrieving from the cache, you reverse the process.  Create a ByteStream from the byte[] returned by the caching API; create an ObjectStream from the ByteStream; read your collection from the ObjectStream.