# Converting from object to byte array and back in java

Tags: java, serialization, arrays

I have two classes: TcpPacket and IpPacket. The tcpPacket should be stored in the data field of the ip packet. How can I reliably convert the tcpPacket object to a byte array so that i can store it in the IpPacket's data field? And upon receiving the packet on the other side, how to reliably convert it back into a packet object?

```
public static final class TcpPacket {
    int source;
    int destination;

    public Packet( int source, int destination ) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Source: " + source + ", Dest: " + destination;
    }
}

public static final class IpPacket {
    byte[] data;

    IpPacket( byte[] data ){
        this.data = data;
    }
}

TcpPacket tcpPacket = new TcpPacket( <someint>, <someint> );

// the following doesn't work because tcppacket is not a byte array.
IpPacket ipPacket = new IpPacket( tcpPacket );
```

How is this usually done?

Thanks Maricruzz

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837698/converting-any-object-to-a-byte-array-in-java

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736058/java-object-to-byte-and-byte-to-object-converter-for-tokyo-cabinet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, just cast the object to your class after receiving it from the serialize/deserialize function.

```
public static byte[] objToByte(TcpPacket tcpPacket) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
    objStream.writeObject(tcpPacket);

    return byteStream.toByteArray();
}

public static Object byteToObj(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteStream);

    return objStream.readObject();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer you the manual approach to serialising your class.

```
public static final class TcpPacket {

    public byte [] toByteArray() {
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 * 2);
        return b.putInt(source).putInt(destination).array();
    }

    public static TcpPacket fromByteArray(byte [] bytes) {
        if (bytes.length < 8) throw new IllegalArgumentException("not enough bytes");

        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        int source = b.getInt();
        int destination = b.getInt();
        return new TcpPacket(source, destination);
    }
}
```

Adding a `toByteArray` and static `fromByteArray` methods would get you what you want and has the following benefits:

- Very small representation, only 8 bytes, could in theory be smaller with variable length encoding of the integers
- Doesn't expose your application to Java serialisation security issues, as clearly you are going to be deserialising data from a network connection.

If you require a serializing more complex data structures I would very strongly recommend you choose a well established serialization library such as [google protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) (my personal weapon of choice) or one of the many others that don't suffer from the security nightmare that is Java serialization.