# java get byte from object that is not serializibe

Tags: java

Is there a way to get the bytes of an object that doesn't implement serializeble?
In cpp i know you can just copy size of the object bytes from the address of the object in the memory, is there a way to do this in java?

edit: I don't really see how that is a duplication of [Converting any object to a byte array in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837698/converting-any-object-to-a-byte-array-in-java) by just to clarify i meant convert a specific non serilizable object

Comment: Why do you want to get the bytes from a non serializable object?

Comment: You should get at least two techniques, but it is not so easy - C struct byte data (memory) cast to an object. Such is more an area for ByteBufferl, DataInputStream.

Comment: Its an object i get from the operation system so i can't make it implement serializible

Comment: @kill129 my recommendation to you is just to get the information you need and create a new class that contains that information and that is Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible to get the raw bytes of an object. Java doesn't have such a view of the world, where objects even have an underlying byte representation.

Note that serialization doesn't give you access to the byte representation of an object either. Serialization is a way of encoding the information in an object into a byte array. It doesn't give you the raw bytes. If you somehow searched through memory for those serialized bytes you wouldn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not and most likely because Serialization is a Java mechanism that provides a representation in bytes of values, types and parameter types. I recommend you read this introduction to [serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm).