# Convert Arraylist<Object> value in to byte[]

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I m trying to get/convert the value of Arraylist in byte[] 
below is my code

```
final ArrayList<Object> imglists = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

this is my arraylist of Objects in this arraylist m storing the values of images in form of bytes

```
for (int i=0; i<mPlaylistVideos.size();i++) {
    holder.mThumbnailImage.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap= holder.mThumbnailImage.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bs);
    byte[] rough = bs.toByteArray();
    imglists.add(i,rough);
}
```

I m trying to get the  specific value from arraylist and store that in byte[]
this is what I was trying to do

```
byte[] value=imglists.get(2);
```

I could not find any complete answer to convert Arraylist of Object into byte[] 
I know Arraylist doesn't support primitive datatype (i-e byte)

Comment: you want ArrayLIst of byte[]?

Comment: Why not define ArrayList<byte[]> instead of ArrayList<Object>

Comment: A java object is a serializable. you can convert object to String and after that convert it to byte[].

Comment: @DeendayalGarg nop i dont want arraylist of byte arraylist dosn't support byte[] . i just want to get the Arraylist<Object> value in to byte[] as i mentioned in my question

Comment: @AmmY converting into string is fine but when i convert it back into byte[] values doesn't match

Comment: @AmmY Arraylist doesn't support byte[] its primitive data type

Comment: I think this will help you. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5837739/2362301

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `List` of `byte[]`, something like that:

```
List<byte[]> imglists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can simply add your `byte array` to your `List` using the [`add(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) method as next:

```
imglists.add(bs.toByteArray());
```

You will then be able to access to a given `byte array` from its index in the `List` using the method [`get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) as you try to achieve:

```
// Get the 3th element of my list
byte[] value = imglists.get(2);
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Thanks Bro this is what i was looking for Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert ArrayList to byte[] ? or Object to byte[]?

I wrote in this way, just simply convert the element in ArrayList into byte[] ,it works!

```
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    objects.add("HelloWorld".getBytes());

    byte[] bytes = (byte[]) objects.get(0);

    System.out.println(new String(bytes));  // HelloWorld
```